# enzyme assert react component as children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have this Input component that will have prop to show an Error component, I'm struggling to find a solution using enzyme.

```
import Error from './Error'
const inputShallow = (props = {}) => shallow(<Input {...props} />)

describe.only('when there is an error', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          props.error = 'This is an error'
          InputContainerInstance = inputShallow(props)
          ErrorInstance = InputContainerInstance.children().find(
            `.error`
          )
        })
        it('Should contain the "Error" component', () => {
          //what to do here hmmm??
        })
      })
```

Tried `expect(ErrorInstance.contains(<Error />)).to.equal(true)` but won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest way to verify the rendering of a component is to use snapshot testing.

Since you are already using enzyme, just add [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json#enzyme-to-json) as a dev dependency and add this

```
"jest": {
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
  ]
}
```

to your package.json (or just add the "snapshotSerializers" if you already have a "jest" key).

Then in your test you can do the following:

`expect(InputContainerInstance).toMatchSnapshot();`

enzyme-to-json creates a very nicely formatted snapshot that is easy to verify visually.

Comment: @JennyTeng did this give you the info you needed?